# Passing system variables with maven-surefire-plugin in Maven

Tags: variables, maven

I'd like to pass some system variables for a Maven build. If i use `mvn clean install -Dfirst.variable=value -Dsecond.variable=second.value` everything's fine. But this configuration in the `pom.xml` doesn't work:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <first.variable>${value}</first.variable>
                            <second.variable>${second.value}</second.variable>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I tried to use this config without `<id/>`, `<phase/>` and `<goals>` but it didn't help. Is there a possibility the plugin doesn't run? Even hardcoded values of these variables don't pass. If so, what is a probable solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don´t need to create an `<execution/>`. The easy way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <my.property>propertyValue</my.property>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I'm pretty sure I saw a code sample with <executions>, that was supposed to work fine. What is the reason of such a behavior?

Comment: Is it required to set variables like this in order for them to pass-through to tests?