# Why does maven execution configuration don't work for the failsafe plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have problems to understand how failsave execution configuration should work.

I can't understand why this execution configuration doesn't work. But if I change to plugin configuration it would work.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>myId</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!--This doesn't work -->
                <skipITs>true</skipITs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!--This would work-->
        <!--<skipITs>true</skipITs>-->
    </configuration>

</plugin>
```

The [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247216/passing-system-variables-with-maven-surefire-plugin-in-maven) problem seems to be described here. Since I want to use different executions with different configurations a configuration on plugin-level don't work for me.

Comment: How are you invoking Maven? What exactly is the command you are running?

Comment: the mvn command is mvn verify

Comment: so the execution configuration will work if I don't set the execution ID.

Comment: Try to remove `<phase>integration-test</phase>`.